# How can I use text input as mathematical symbols?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a form where the two first input fields accept numbers and the third one the symbol and then the result is calculated and shown as in the image. [my goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsV6l.png)

my code so far is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<style>
form {
 background-color:cyan;
 border:solid 1px blue; 
 padding:2px;
 width:500px;
 }
#lf{
 background-color:#ccc;
 border:solid 3px black;
 padding:4px;
 } 
form td { background-color:cyan;  
 font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
 } 
#resultSt{
 color:#C00;
 font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-weight:bolder;
 animation:ease-in;
 }
</style>


<script>
   var $original = null;

   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").keyup(function(){
     var a=$("#1").val();
     var b=$("#2").val();
     var c=$("#3").val();
     var d=addnumbers(a,b);
     $("span").append(d);
     
     if(d>5){     
      $("span").css({"color":"green"});
      $("span").css({"font-weight":"bold"});
     }
     else{
      $("span").css({"color":"red"});
      $("span").css({"font-weight":"bold"});
     } 
    });
    $("p").mouseout(function(){
     $("span").html($original);
    });
    
    function addnumbers(a,b){
     var c=Number(a)+Number(b);
     return c;
    }
   });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

<section>

<article>

<form>
<table >
<tr>
<td>First Number:</td>
<td><input type="number" id="1" name="first" size="30" required="required" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Second Number:</td>
<td><input type="number" id="2" name="second" size="30" required="required"  ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Symbol:</td>
<td> <label for="symbol"></i>
</label>
 <input name="symbol" id="3" pattern="[+ - * / ]">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Result is:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="city" size="30" ></td>
</tr>

</table> <br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="sb">
</form>

</article>

</section>


</body>
</html>
```

i just cant find a way to make the function accept symbols from Symbol input field. Do you guys have any suggestions, solutions.

thank you!
PS: I am newbie in coding.

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, you could use a `switch` statement, eg:

```
var a=$("#1").val() * 1;  // *1 gets the value and ensures it's a number
var b=$("#2").val() * 1;
var op=$("#3").val();     // get the operation 
var d;

// equivalent of:  if (op == "+") .. else if (op == "-") 
switch (op) {
    case "+": d=a+b; break;
    case "-": d=a-b; break;
    case "*": d=a*b; break;
    default: alert("unrecognised operation"); break;
}
```

Working sample:

```js
var $original = null;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").keyup(function() {
    var a = $("#1").val() * 1;
    var b = $("#2").val() * 1;
    var c = $("#3").val();
    var op = $("#3").val();
    var d;
    switch (op) {
      case "+":
        d = a + b;
        break;
      case "-":
        d = a - b;
        break;
      case "*":
        d = a * b;
        break;
      default:
        d = "unrecognised operation";
        break;
    }
    $("span").text(d);
  });
});
```

```css
form {
  background-color: cyan;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 500px;
}

#lf {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: solid 3px black;
  padding: 4px;
}

form td {
  background-color: cyan;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}

#resultSt {
  color: #C00;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  animation: ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</style>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First Number:</td>
    <td><input type="number" id="1" name="first" size="30" required="required"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Second Number:</td>
    <td><input type="number" id="2" name="second" size="30" required="required"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Symbol:</td>
    <td>
      <input name="symbol" id="3" pattern="[+ - * / ]">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Result is:</td>
    <td><span><span></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: You are the best! Thank you very much for the help!!!

Comment: As someone just starting out, I feel this will be your best approach.  The accepted answer on the duplicate link is very clean approach, but not too obvious how/why it works when you're starting out - and you need to know about `switch` anyway.